# discord embed doesn't run properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to send an embed with my discord but, it just gives me an error.

My code:

```js
 const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setTitle("Info")
.setURL("https://www.fajaryusuf.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/fajaryusuf.com-zhongli-Genshin-Impact.jpga")
.setAuthor("Programmer: Acezx#7591", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQzjDisyw2UagcPjVWj0jOxhXWKd5ssesskQ&usqp=CAU","https://www.fajaryusuf.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/fajaryusuf.com-zhongli-Genshin-Impact.jpg")
.setColor('#e10e0e')
.setDescription("Info about The_ModBot")
.setFooter("Info, https://www.fajaryusuf.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/fajaryusuf.com-zhongli-Genshin-Impact.jpg")
.setImage("https://cdn.kincir.com/2/D47_jABuH801rq6yQPCK7Cm-m7yDH_w3jN-jZst--SQ/transform/rs:fill:764:400/src/production/2021-04/16by9/zhongli-1-5~69a0c2e9-4e03-4376-9a7c-c471dc3f240c.jpg")
.setThumbnail("https://www.siliconera.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/genshin-impact-zhongli.jpg")
.setTimestamp()
 
 client.on("message", message => {
   if (message.content === ";info") {
     message.channel.send({embed})
   }
 })
```

The error I recieve:

```
Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15) 
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27) 
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19) 
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16) 
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15) 
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27) 
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19) 
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16) 
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:1:15
```

Comment: How is it not working? Is there a specific error message it gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple answer to this: your footer is not set correctly. You have to have a comma separating your text and your image. You just forgot to place 2 `"`. Try this:

```js
.setFooter(
  "Info", 
  "https://www.fajaryusuf.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/fajaryusuf.com-zhongli-Genshin-Impact.jpg"
)
```

Comment: Try MessageEmbed. RichEmbend is from an old Version of discord.js